# Confusion in working of Decimal and Round function

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, decimal, rounding, decimal-point

I am trying to understand how the round and decimal function of Python actually works. For this I tried to run this code:

`from decimal import Decimal
print("An integer %i and a float %.1f" %(23, 6.549))
print Decimal(6.549)
print Decimal(45.0)/Decimal(7)
print Decimal(45.0/7)`

I got the output:

```
An integer 23 and a float 6.5
6.54900000000000037658764995285309851169586181640625
6.428571428571428571428571429
6.4285714285714288251938342000357806682586669921875
```

1. I tried to understand the working of round function from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues), it describes that 6.549 is converted to a binary floating point number and is replaced by a binary approximation. I am confused about where does the approximation in extended value from Decimal(6.549) comes from. Also, can I assume that rounding off of every decimal value will work in the same way or will it depend on the individual binary approximation?
2. When I use the Decimal function in two different ways, it gives a slightly different value. Also, one value has more precision than the other. Can someone please specify the reason for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Decimal` can't fix what has already been broken.

Comment: Are you passing floating-point values to Decimal() on purpose (because you want to see what they look like) or do you want true decimal values? (If the latter, use single quotes around your inputs.)

Comment: I was using floating-point values on purpose because I wanted to see which value they are being rounded to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about where does the approximation in extended value from Decimal(6.549) comes from.

The literal `6.549` is first converted to a floating point number, which is stored in binary: as 6.549 cannot be stored exactly in this format, it is rounded to the nearest value which is in fact

6.54900000000000037658764995285309851169586181640625

(see [Rick Regan's floating point converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) for more details).

To avoid this intermediate rounding, pass a string instead:

```
>>> Decimal("6.549")
Decimal('6.549')
```

> Also, can I assume that rounding off of every decimal value will work in the same way or will it depend on the individual binary approximation?

Yes, all numeric literals will have this problem (unless they can be represented exactly in binary, such as `45.0` and `7`).

> When I use the Decimal function in two different ways, it gives a slightly different value. Also, one value has more precision than the other. Can someone please specify the reason for this?

Due to the same problem above: `Decimal(45.0)/Decimal(7)` will first convert the literals `45.0` and `7` to decimals (which can be done exactly), then perform the division using the extended precision decimal library.

`Decimal(45.0/7)` on the other hand converts both `45.0` and `7` to floating point numbers (which is exact), but then performs the division at floating point precision (which is only accurate to about 16 significant digits). This result is then converted to decimal (including the erroneous extra digits).

Comment: So, the result of `Decimal(45.0/7)` is incorrect as compared to result of `Decimal(45.0)/Decimal(7)` , right?

Comment: The latter is more accurate yes: the true answer is a recurring decimal, so can't be represented exactly by a finite length decimal (or binary) approximation.